# TiKz externalization ignoring scale

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I want to use a TikZ picture (an Eiffel tower but it does not matter) a lots of times in the same document, but with different sizes and different colors.

The first option could have been to define a `\newcommand`. But it would have meant that TikZ would have been called several times to draw the same picture, plus an heavier pdf file.

I chose to do the following :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figs/]
\newcommand{\eiffeldessin}{(15.1496,157.9474) .. controls (15.1496,156.2479) and
  (19.1646,154.7631) .. (26.7002,153.6759) .. controls (29.7886,153.2304) and
  (31.2269,152.4980) .. (31.5669,151.1977) .. controls (31.8323,150.1826) and
  (32.4135,149.3520) .. (32.8584,149.3520) .. controls (33.3032,149.3520) and
  (36.6624,145.8645) .. (40.3233,141.6020) .. controls (47.4569,133.2960) and
  (56.7746,117.3833) .. (56.8005,113.4623) .. controls (56.8092,112.1479) and
  (57.4397,110.5729) .. (58.2017,109.9623) .. controls (60.5777,108.0583) and
  (67.0690,86.7792) .. (66.3176,83.3579) .. controls (65.9019,81.4654) and
  (66.0572,80.3520) .. (66.7368,80.3520) .. controls (67.3305,80.3520) and
  (67.8256,79.1145) .. (67.8370,77.6020) .. controls (67.8484,76.0895) and
  (68.7505,69.4520) .. (69.8415,62.8520) .. controls (73.2163,42.4378) and
  (74.4038,24.4695) .. (72.8156,17.8491) .. controls (71.6200,12.8653) and
  (71.6471,11.7949) .. (73.0391,9.0151) .. controls (73.9102,7.2754) and
  (74.8773,5.0645) .. (75.1882,4.1020) .. controls (75.9775,1.6585) and
  (78.8163,1.8858) .. (78.8163,4.3925) .. controls (78.8163,5.5148) and
  (79.7754,7.7302) .. (80.9475,9.3157) .. controls (82.5313,11.4578) and
  (82.8975,12.9246) .. (82.3731,15.0252) .. controls (80.8898,20.9668) and
  (80.6433,31.9936) .. (81.7563,42.6228) .. controls (82.9932,54.4362) and
  (86.5156,76.8731) .. (87.5225,79.3520) .. controls (87.8576,80.1770) and
  (88.0346,81.4424) .. (87.9160,82.1639) .. controls (87.6316,83.8929) and
  (89.4674,92.9651) .. (92.0517,102.6020) .. controls (93.6907,108.7137) and
  (94.5197,110.3520) .. (95.9732,110.3520) .. controls (96.9869,110.3520) and
  (97.8163,111.0270) .. (97.8163,111.8520) .. controls (97.8163,112.6770) and
  (97.3606,113.3520) .. (96.8037,113.3520) .. controls (94.4636,113.3520) and
  (107.4966,135.9884) .. (116.1534,146.9596) .. controls (120.0438,151.8901) and
  (120.5454,152.1999) .. (123.8163,151.6929) .. controls (128.8912,150.9064) and
  (141.6332,148.3413) .. (143.6175,147.7067) .. controls (144.9326,147.2861) and
  (145.0084,147.3832) .. (143.9531,148.1367) .. controls (142.8023,148.9584) and
  (142.8023,149.1881) .. (143.9531,149.6118) .. controls (147.7101,150.9950) and
  (127.9225,155.9799) .. (112.5933,157.5120) .. controls (103.4131,158.4295) and
  (96.4720,158.4032) .. (80.5933,157.3905) .. controls (69.4409,156.6793) and
  (54.4663,156.3470) .. (47.3163,156.6522) .. controls (34.3838,157.2041) and
  (31.3883,157.4485) .. (20.7329,158.8214) .. controls (15.9902,159.4325) and
  (15.1496,159.3009) .. (15.1496,157.9474) -- cycle(85.0663,154.6898) ..
  controls (84.3788,154.4123) and (83.2538,154.4123) .. (82.5663,154.6898) ..
  controls (81.8788,154.9672) and (82.4413,155.1941) .. (83.8163,155.1941) ..
  controls (85.1913,155.1941) and (85.7538,154.9672) .. (85.0663,154.6898) --
  cycle(116.5455,154.7478) .. controls (38.8485,158.2493) and (77.6970,156.4986)
  .. (116.5455,154.7478) -- cycle(74.0853,153.6961) .. controls
  (73.4083,153.4222) and (72.0583,153.4055) .. (71.0853,153.6590) .. controls
  (70.1123,153.9125) and (70.6663,154.1366) .. (72.3163,154.1570) .. controls
  (73.9663,154.1774) and (74.7623,153.9700) .. (74.0853,153.6960) --
  cycle(95.0229,150.6525) .. controls (94.7810,149.3873) and (94.1997,148.3520)
  .. (93.7311,148.3520) .. controls (93.2625,148.3520) and (93.1381,147.6770) ..
  (93.4547,146.8520) .. controls (93.7712,146.0270) and (93.5321,145.3520) ..
  (92.9233,145.3520) .. controls (90.7200,147.8788) and (92.0102,153.0524) ..
  (90.3824,147.0195) .. controls (87.3946,135.9031) and (77.2251,129.3512) ..
  (71.2663,134.7036) .. controls (67.2960,138.0570) and (63.5425,142.6797) ..
  (61.4978,146.5118) -- (59.9937,150.1717) -- (70.1550,150.8659) .. controls
  (75.7437,151.2478) and (83.0163,151.8860) .. (86.3163,152.2840) .. controls
  (95.1760,153.3528) and (95.5265,153.2871) .. (95.0229,150.6525) --
  cycle(117.5223,152.1493) .. controls (118.1856,152.0775) and
  (118.4920,151.6363) .. (118.2032,151.1690) .. controls (117.0519,150.1033) and
  (113.1833,151.2641) .. (112.7161,151.1519) .. controls (111.9579,150.8992) and
  (110.1802,148.4783) .. (108.7658,145.7722) .. controls (107.3514,143.0661) and
  (104.8595,139.0106) .. (103.2283,136.7599) .. controls (101.5971,134.5093) and
  (99.4187,130.7968) .. (98.3875,128.5099) .. controls (94.4707,117.6272) and
  (97.3465,131.2963) .. (93.6104,117.4392) -- (92.6143,113.5148) --
  (84.4653,113.0228) .. controls (77.0493,112.5751) and (73.9959,112.5965) ..
  (64.0663,113.1657) .. controls (62.2788,113.2682) and (60.8877,113.6896) ..
  (60.9750,114.1021) .. controls (61.0624,114.5146) and (60.7777,115.7521) ..
  (60.3425,116.8521) .. controls (59.9072,117.9521) and (58.5329,121.4525) ..
  (57.2883,124.6308) .. controls (54.4079,131.9870) and (49.3824,140.3584) ..
  (44.4813,145.9651) .. controls (42.3721,148.3779) and (41.0221,150.3896) ..
  (41.4813,150.4354) .. controls (41.9405,150.4812) and (43.4413,150.6858) ..
  (44.8163,150.8901) .. controls (46.1913,151.0943) and (49.3541,151.0283) ..
  (51.8447,150.7434) .. controls (56.3490,150.2281) and (56.3795,150.1985) ..
  (57.5715,145.1801) .. controls (61.2379,129.7456) and (73.9302,122.3547) ..
  (85.9090,128.6788) .. controls (91.8185,131.7987) and (95.4724,137.3004) ..
  (97.5643,146.2282) -- (99.2927,153.6042) -- (107.8045,152.9421) .. controls
  (112.4860,152.5779) and (116.8590,152.2212) .. (117.5223,152.1493) --
  cycle(37.1130,148.8206) .. controls (39.4235,145.6460) and (38.8143,145.6608)
  .. (35.8163,148.8520) .. controls (34.5245,150.2270) and (33.8836,151.3379) ..
  (34.3920,151.3206) .. controls (34.9003,151.3033) and (36.1248,150.1783) ..
  (37.1130,148.8206) -- cycle(39.9438,148.6020) .. controls (41.1877,147.0160)
  and (41.1523,146.9806) .. (39.5663,148.2245) .. controls (38.6038,148.9793)
  and (37.8163,149.7668) .. (37.8163,149.9745) .. controls (37.8163,150.7975)
  and (38.6375,150.2678) .. (39.9438,148.6020) -- cycle(91.4443,141.5997) ..
  controls (90.6615,140.0859) and (89.0184,137.9484) .. (87.7928,136.8497) ..
  controls (85.8160,135.0774) and (85.8609,135.2908) .. (88.1905,138.7416) ..
  controls (89.6347,140.8808) and (90.8163,143.0183) .. (90.8163,143.4916) ..
  controls (90.8163,143.9648) and (91.2778,144.3520) .. (91.8420,144.3520) ..
  controls (92.4466,144.3520) and (92.2833,143.2221) .. (91.4443,141.5997) --
  cycle(71.8460,130.9355) .. controls (73.7547,130.1076) and (74.7314,129.4127)
  .. (74.0166,129.3912) .. controls (72.0628,129.3324) and (67.3573,131.9797) ..
  (65.7607,134.0361) .. controls (64.4169,135.7668) and (64.4452,135.7720) ..
  (66.3633,134.1464) .. controls (67.4702,133.2083) and (69.9374,131.7634) ..
  (71.8460,130.9355) -- cycle(72.5779,110.6649) .. controls (71.6219,110.4147)
  and (69.8219,110.4056) .. (68.5779,110.6447) .. controls (67.3340,110.8839)
  and (68.1163,111.0887) .. (70.3163,111.0998) .. controls (72.5163,111.1109)
  and (73.5340,110.9152) .. (72.5779,110.6649) -- cycle(84.0663,110.6463) ..
  controls (82.8288,110.4080) and (80.8038,110.4080) .. (79.5663,110.6463) ..
  controls (78.3288,110.8847) and (79.3413,111.0797) .. (81.8163,111.0797) ..
  controls (84.2913,111.0797) and (85.3038,110.8847) .. (84.0663,110.6463) --
  cycle(67.3983,108.7657) .. controls (69.1272,108.3014) and (69.6795,106.9255)
  .. (70.6548,100.6519) .. controls (71.9429,92.3663) and (73.4213,88.5922) ..
  (76.0077,86.9863) .. controls (78.4099,85.4948) and (81.3145,88.4004) ..
  (82.9464,93.9272) .. controls (83.6650,96.3609) and (84.6312,98.3520) ..
  (85.0936,98.3520) .. controls (85.5560,98.3520) and (85.6554,98.8034) ..
  (85.3145,99.3550) .. controls (84.9735,99.9066) and (84.9981,102.3816) ..
  (85.3690,104.8550) .. controls (85.9345,108.6262) and (86.4005,109.3520) ..
  (88.2560,109.3520) -- (90.4686,109.3520) -- (88.1897,102.6020) .. controls
  (86.9364,98.8895) and (85.6169,93.5225) .. (85.2575,90.6753) .. controls
  (77.9101,80.5979) and (76.4922,78.4245) .. (71.9328,82.7820) .. controls
  (71.4764,83.3705) and (70.5451,86.7702) .. (69.8632,90.3369) .. controls
  (69.1812,93.9035) and (67.3449,99.6410) .. (65.7825,103.0869) .. controls
  (62.9260,109.3866) and (63.0793,109.9254) .. (67.3983,108.7657) --
  cycle(81.9932,105.6020) -- (81.4474,102.8520) -- (80.7315,105.3520) ..
  controls (80.2046,107.1922) and (79.9893,107.3548) .. (79.9160,105.9680) ..
  controls (79.7609,103.0368) and (77.5816,96.3520) .. (76.7811,96.3520) ..
  controls (76.3858,96.3520) and (75.3823,99.0520) .. (74.5510,102.3520) --
  (73.0396,108.3520) -- (77.7893,108.3520) .. controls (82.4364,108.3520) and
  (82.5272,108.2926) .. (81.9932,105.6020) -- cycle(78.8163,94.3520) .. controls
  (78.1182,92.6668) and (77.3335,91.5015) .. (77.0724,91.7625) .. controls
  (76.8114,92.0236) and (77.1961,93.5889) .. (77.9274,95.2409) .. controls
  (79.6617,99.1589) and (80.4718,98.3488) .. (78.8163,94.3520) --
  cycle(81.3879,74.6020) .. controls (80.2835,69.4308) and (77.8165,48.9864) ..
  (77.6849,43.9156) -- (77.5535,38.8520) -- (76.7375,43.8520) .. controls
  (76.2887,46.6020) and (75.1814,54.6607) .. (74.2769,61.7601) .. controls
  (73.3723,68.8595) and (72.4005,75.2720) .. (72.1173,76.0101) .. controls
  (71.7273,77.0264) and (72.8609,77.3520) .. (76.7887,77.3520) .. controls
  (81.9224,77.3520) and (81.9692,77.3240) .. (81.3879,74.6020) --
  cycle(78.1741,13.4187) .. controls (77.3098,12.4612) and (75.6451,15.2660) ..
  (76.3759,16.4485) .. controls (76.9561,17.3872) and (77.3447,17.2140) ..
  (77.8633,15.7857) .. controls (78.2493,14.7222) and (78.3892,13.6570) ..
  (78.1741,13.4187) -- cycle;}

\NewDocumentCommand{\eiffel}{O{1}O{LimeGreen}}{%
\IfFileExists{figs/eiffel_#2.pdf}{\includegraphics[scale=#1]{figs/eiffel_#2.pdf}}{%
\tikzsetnextfilename{eiffel_#2}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1pt, x=1pt, yscale=-0.1*#1, xscale=0.1*#1,inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt    ]
\path[fill=#2] \eiffeldessin
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}
\eiffel \eiffel[2] \eiffel[3]

\eiffel[1][red] \eiffel[5][red] \eiffel[4][Cerulean]   
\end{document}
```

More precisely, the command `\eiffel` takes to optional arguments : a size and a color.
Different files corresponding to different colors will be created as eiffel_black.pdf, eiffel_red.pdf, eiffel_LimeGreen.pdf, etc, according to different color names.
The file is created the first time `\eiffel` is called with the color names, and the next times, this file is just included with `\includegraphics`.

This seems to work just fine, as the example provided below produces the following output :

[image]

However, the first time a color is called, the file is created with a size depending of the scaling factor of this first call. For instance, if I add `\eiffel[1][Cerulean]` to the previous example, I will get a new blue Eiffel tower which has the same size than the previous. I understand why this is happening, but I would like this new blue tower to be four times smaller than the previous.

So my question is : is there some way to "forget" the scale factor while creating the externalized picture but still apply it to my document when the first call of `\eiffel` with a new color is made with a scaling factor different from 1.

An alternative could also to be able to externalize a picture without including it in the document (I mean creating a non scaled externalized pdf a the first call and then include it with the desired scale). If there is an easy way to do so, it is sufficient for me.

Comment: An option is to remove the scaling options in `tikzpicture`, so that the image is always created with a fixed size. 
All the pictures will have the desired size after the second compilation, but when you think about it, most documents need several compilations...

Comment: Your follow-up question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263539/troubles-with-hyperref-and-tikz-externalization appears to contain the answer of @mvienney , and it appears to work (with two compilations as claimed by @mvienney).

Comment: can you convert your comment into an answer? I suppose you can copy the example code from my answer in the linked question