# Troubles with hyperref and Tikz externalization

Tags: hyperref, tikz-external

Consider the following example :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./]


\NewDocumentCommand{\mypic}{O{red}O{1}}{%
\IfFileExists{mypic_#1.pdf}{\includegraphics[scale=#2]{mypic_#1.pdf}}{%
\tikzsetnextfilename{mypic_#1}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[#1] (1,0)--(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}

\mypic[Cerulean] \mypic[Cyan] \mypic[red] \mypic[YellowGreen]

\end{document}
```

The command `\mypic` is supposed to include a picture whose color is included in the file name if such a file exists, or to create the pdf picture if it was not created before.
It is not working on my computer, and I the error message I get is

```
 Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "./mypic_Cerulean"  "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{EIFFEL}\input{EIFFEL}"' did NOT result in a usable output file
```

However, when removing the `hyperref`package, it works just fine. I've read a few threads about the interactions of `hyperref` and TikZ externalization but none of the solutions I've tried worked for me. Is there anything I can do ?

Even stranger : keeping `hyperref` but removing the `\IfFileExists` part, it sill works (but does not allow me to change the scale of the pictures). Where does this come from ?

Comment: Once those pdfs /are generated the error dose not exist anymore. Can you manage to work on your .tex without `hyperref` temporarily?

Comment: Yes I can, and that's indeed what I did, but it kind of loses the interest of such a command...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is not directly related to `hyperref`; the root cause is that you are trying to skip the picture *while it is being generated*. This results in a 0-size pdf, and that is deleted right-away by `pdftex`.

This is what happens:

- the main program is typeset, and this is where your "if image exists" logic should apply. It does not since the graphics does not exist.
- the externalization is started. To this end, it starts to generate the picture (let us assume it starts with mypic_Cerulean). Then it checks if `mypic_Cerulean.pdf` exists -- which is true if the pdf's header has already been written.
- Your 'if' strips the picture code as such, and the externalization results in an *empty* output file.
- pdftex removes the started pdf file since it contains no output.
- The main program tries to include the file but fails to find it.

Thus, the logic is essentially a programming error in your script: it must not apply the "if image exists" while it is currently about to generate it.

The reason why `hyperref` makes a difference is that `hyperref` (appears to) generate some header information in the output pdf, i.e. it causes the file to be written before the first shipout starts. Note that `hyperref` is not the only tool which generates such header information, but in this case, it makes the difference.

You have to use `\tikzifexternalizing` in order to fix the problem. It works with the following modification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./]


\NewDocumentCommand{\mypic}{O{red}O{1}}{%
    \tikzifexternalizing{%
        \def\DOIT{1}%
    }{%
        \IfFileExists{mypic_#1.pdf}{%
            \includegraphics[scale=#2]{mypic_#1.pdf}%
            \def\DOIT{0}%
        }{%
            \def\DOIT{1}%
        }%
    }%
    %
    \if1\DOIT
        \tikzsetnextfilename{mypic_#1}%
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[#1] (1,0)--(0,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\mypic[Cerulean] \mypic[Cyan] \mypic[red] \mypic[YellowGreen]

\end{document}
```

The key idea is to apply your special logic only during the generation of the main .tex file, but omit it if the externalization is running.

The `\def\DOIT{<value>}` stores `<value>` into the macro `\DOIT`. The `\if1\DOIT` is a 1-char-comparison which checks if `\DOIT` expands to "1". This check works if and only if `\DOIT` expands to at most one character (which is satisfied here: it can hold `1` or `0`).

Answer (score 5):

<del>I cannot explain the error. Do not give me the bounty.</del> (see next section)

Assuming your MWE, `\scalebox` works. Let me know if you intend to achieve something more complicated. By the way, whatever your goal is, the logic is that `external` is superior to `\IfFileExists`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse,hyperref}
\usetikzlibrary{external}\tikzexternalize
\NewDocumentCommand{\mypic}{O{red}O{1}}{
    \tikzsetnextfilename{mypic_#1}
    \scalebox{#2}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[#1] (1,0)--(0,1);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
}
\begin{document}
    \mypic[Cerulean]    \mypic[Cyan]    \mypic[red]    \mypic[YellowGreen]
    \mypic[Cerulean][1] \mypic[Cyan][2] \mypic[red][3] \mypic[YellowGreen][4]
\end{document}
```

## What causes the error?

Before I can answer the question, I want to talk about the library `external`.

### Question: How does `external` work?

#### Wrong answer:

It extracts the code between `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`. And then runs that piece of code.

You can prove that this is wrong by adding some global setting outside:

```
    \tikzset{
        every picture/.style={ ... }
    }
```

#### Correct answer:

It calls `pdftex` to run the original file again, but this time:

- the output routine is suppressed, unless it meets the `tikzpicture`;
- it passes `-jobname "name_of_that_picture"` as an option, so this run would end up with `name_of_that_picture.pdf`.

This mechanism is explained in the manual, currently part IX The Basic Layer section 107 Externalizing Graphics.

### So ... what exactly happens normally?

Image that you call `pdftex`:

- `pdftex` runs `your_article.tex`;
- `pdftex` reaches `\mypic{Cerulean}`;
- `pdftex` tries `\IfFileExists{mypic_Cerulean.pdf}`, but in vain;
- `pdftex` decides to generated `mypic_Cerulean.pdf`;
- `pdftex` calls another `pdftex -jobname "mypic_Cerulean"`;

  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> runs `your_article.tex`;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> reaches `\mypic{Cerulean}`;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> tries `\IfFileExists{mypic_Cerulean.pdf}`, but in vain;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> decides to typeset the `tikzpicture`;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> finishes, leaves `mypic_Cerulean.pdf` on the disk;
- `pdftex` is happy to see the result, `mypic_Cerulean.pdf` included;
- `pdftex` reaches `\mypic{Cyan}`;
- `pdftex` tries `\IfFileExists{mypic_ Cyan.pdf}`, but in vain;
- `pdftex` decides to generated `mypic_ Cyan.pdf`;
- `pdftex` calls another `pdftex -jobname "mypic_ Cyan"`;

  - `pdftex`<sub>3</sub> runs `your_article.tex`;

and so on...

### So ... why `hyperref` causes the error?

- `pdftex` runs `your_article.tex`;
- `pdftex` includes `hyperref`, `your_article.pdf` created;
- `pdftex` reaches `\mypic{Cerulean}`;
- `pdftex` tries `\IfFileExists{mypic_Cerulean.pdf}`, but in vain;
- `pdftex` decides to generated `mypic_Cerulean.pdf`;
- `pdftex` calls another `pdftex -jobname "mypic_Cerulean"`;

  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> runs `your_article.tex`;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> includes `hyperref`, `mypic_Cerulean.pdf` created;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> reaches `\mypic{Cerulean}`;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> tries `\IfFileExists{mypic_Cerulean.pdf}`, successes;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> decides to include `mypic_Cerulean.pdf`, but in vain;
  - `pdftex`<sub>2</sub> terminates with `Fatal error`;
- `pdftex` is unhappy to see no `mypic_Cerulean.pdf`;
- `pdftex` pauses and throws the error you saw;

## Other workarounds

Try not to test the file by yourself. If you really want to do so, mimic the way PGF testing files. If you just want to control `\includegraphics`, PGF provides `/pgf/images/include external`.